# Ruby - redirect_to redirects to the correct page, but isn't changing the URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am teaching myself Ruby and Rails...  and until today, have been feeling pretty good about it.  :)

However, today I ran into an issue I can't seem to crack.  I am practicing by creating a blog.  I have the routes and views set up - and the code will write to the database - but the redirect_to doesn't seem to be working properly.

If the user navigates to: .../article/new, they can enter a new article.  Upon successful submission, the app should redirect to the URL ../article/id, display the article on show.html.erb and flash a message that the article saved successfully.

For some reason, I cannot get the URL redirect portion to work.  The article saves, the show.html.erb displays with the proper message...  but the url stays ../article/new.  If the redirect doesn't work, the rest of the application won't work because other actions require different URLs (../article/id/edit, for example).

I have been using

```
<%= @article.inspect %>
```

on the show page and it looks like everything has saved correctly (which I suspected because it calls the correct view).

Any thoughts would be very, very welcome.  I'm really excited to be learning Ruby and Rails and look forward to getting through this.

articles_controller.rb:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @article = Article.new
  end

  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)
    if @article.save
      flash[:notice] = "Article was successfully created"
      redirect_to article_path(@article)
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  private
  def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :description)
  end
end
```

rake routes:

```
Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                  Controller#Action
        root GET    /                            pages#home
       about GET    /about(.:format)             pages#about
    articles GET    /articles(.:format)          articles#index
             POST   /articles(.:format)          articles#create
 new_article GET    /articles/new(.:format)      articles#new
edit_article GET    /articles/:id/edit(.:format) articles#edit
     article GET    /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#show
             PATCH  /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#update
             PUT    /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#update
             DELETE /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#destroy
```

Comment: Do you use turbolinks in your application?

Comment: I don't...  I'm just whatever comes pre-installed with cloud 9's IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing `article_path` to `article_url`?  This might trigger the  behavior you are looking for.

Comment: Hi - I just tried this, but it didn't work.  I am really, really at a loss... I've been following along in this tutorial and things were going great until I ran into this issue...

Answer (score 0):

After digging around, a friendly user at the cloud9 forums was able to help me figure it out.  I was running the app in a c-9 window...  running it in an actual browser window fixed the problem.

Here is a link to the conversation where it was figured out over at the cloud9 forum:

https://community.c9.io/t/ruby-rails-redirect-to-not-working-properly/3644

And thanks again to Oxyrus for helping me figure it out.